# square connect api obtain token error

Tags: asp.net, square-connect

I've successfully get the code from square from OAuth authorization. But I can't exchange it to get the access token. I get this response:

```
{"message":"Missing required parameter `client_id`","type":"bad_request"}
```

My asp.net implementation is following:

```
    object item = new { client_id = [app_id], client_secret = [app_secret], code = [authCode] };
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var json = serializer.Serialize(item);
    HttpContent content = new StringContent(json, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://connect.squareup.com");
    AuthenticationHeaderValue auth = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", "Client [app_secret]");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = auth;
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> httpResponse = httpCLient.PostAsync("/oauth2/token", content);
    if (httpResponse.Result.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
    }
    string resultContent = httpResponse.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

I got stuck at this point. Don't get why it says that client_id parameter is missing, though I send this parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/disqus-dev/D56s2yMXNxY/-McezaZxOiUJ) solution solved the problem:

Comment: I am facing the same problem in php. Not quiet sure what part of that was the solution, the url encoding?

I tried this in php, but the problem still exists

*curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,urlencode(json_encode($array)));*